# Does anyone know about workflow frameworks/libraries in Python?

Tags: python, django, workflow

I'm searching for a workflow library/framework for Python. I'm astonished that there I cannot find anything which is simple and not attached to Zope/Plone.

Does anyone know of an open-source, simple workflow library/framework. It's preferred to support Django, but not required.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25717038/2810305) provides a conceptual comparison of some frameworks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [GoFlow](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/GoFlow), a workflow engine for Django.

Comment: GoFlow became inactive in 2009. Here is what we have now in 2014 for django - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795328/workflow-frameworks-for-django/25717038#25717038

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it seems like most/all of the projects listed here are no longer active.  Here's a new project which is currently ongoing:

http://packages.python.org/django-workflows/overview.html

Answer (score 4):

Another workflow project that I saw recently was repoze.workflow, which is a state-machine based workflow engine which was inspired by plone, but is a clean re-implementation.

http://svn.repoze.org/repoze.workflow/trunk/docs/index.rst

Not exactly sure how production ready it really is, but I do know some people that are using it.

Comment: repoze.workflow is cool but it's more a statemachine than really complete workflow solution...

Answer (score 1):

I used hurry.workflow: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hurry.workflow
It has plenty of features but unfortunately has some zope dependecies so it may be not applicable for other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

We are actively working on Zops Workflow Engine based on Spiff. You can check if it suits your needs.

https://github.com/zetaops/zengine

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an openerp, but it's not workflow.....

Comment: OpenERP [http://www.openerp.com] has an integrated workflow engine but it cannot be used outsite the OpenERP framework

Answer (score 0):

Besides GoFlow (linked in Oli's answer) the only other Django workflow I know of is part of the [Pinax](http://www.pinaxproject.com) project.

More generally for Python based workflows there is [spiff workflow](http://code.google.com/p/spiff-workflow/) and Dave Kuhlman's [Workflow and REST How-to](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/workflow_howto.html) that could probably be converted from Quixote to Django.

Comment: Gah, I went to look and the 'projects' app is just Project/Task management without any workflow. Sorry for my error :(

Comment: Btw, are you asking because you had problems with GoFlow?  I'm asking because I'll need to implement workflow in Django myself sometime.

Comment: I don't have any specific problems with workflow, but I wanted something which is easier (from my POV, of course :) )

Answer (score 0):

ntoll's [workflow](http://github.com/ntoll/workflow) for django is alpha, but is actively developed

Answer (score 0):

There is also Xworkflows ( https://github.com/rbarrois/xworkflows/ ) and  it's pluggable to django with django-xworkflofws ( https://github.com/rbarrois/django_xworkflows )

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about building workflows with rules? You might checkout http://nebrios.com, a rules based workflow tool. It's built in Python/Django and executes full Python and Django. It's not FOSS though, and doesn't integrate as a library since it's Platform.

Full Disclosure: We built this over the last year since we couldn't find any workflow/process tools that met our needs.